# Python's help() in Maya 2012 acting quite strange

Tags: python, maya, docstring

This seems completely unrelated to the contents of the code, so I'll keep it generic.

I was adding a multiline docstring to the last class at the bottom of one of my modules - just something that adds labels to things - and when I imported the module via Maya's script editor and ran a help(module.Class) on that class, I received this error:

```
# Error: IndexError: file C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2012\bin\python26.zip\inspect.py line 568: list index out of range #
```

I spent awhile narrowing down what about the multiline string was causing the error, paring it down to working with 1 or 2 lines, but failing beyond that. I tried moving the large, multiline comment to another class and doing a help on that, and it worked fine, so it seemed the comment was not at issue. I then did a help on the new last class in the module, and it failed. It seemed like position near the end was the issue.

I moved the comment back to the failing class and removed all of its code and did a help(), and it worked fine. I started adding back in methods, and it worked all the way up until the last one, which had only one line of code in it. I changed every part of it - renamed it, removed args, swapped its one line of code for a pass - help for the class always failed until I removed it outright. Help did work on the module.Class.method, so the method itself, and its big, multiline comment seemed okay.

I then moved the entire class up in the module file to before the class right before it. Help now worked for it. However, now help failed for the last class in the file, though it doesn't even have a docstring. I moved the class back to the bottom, and started playing with the things at the end of it. It seemed to have a problem with the last method, meaning even if I deleted many before them - more text than deleting just the one at the end - I'd still get a problem. I added a docstring to the last method and help failed, but adding a docstring (just a "whatever") to the last three made it work again. This whole thing is completely baffling.

Is this a known issue that I've somehow missed? It seems like some class/method configurations can kill help unless all methods - especially the more than lightly complicated ones - have docstrings.

editing to add a small bit of code as an example:

```
def setLabelChangeDGC (self, control):
    control.dragCallback = self.getLabelChangeDGC(control)
```

That was the final method of the final class in the file. It caused help to crash. Removing this method would allow help to work on the class again. However, leaving this in and moving the class itself above the previous class would cause it to work fine again for this class, but then begin to fail on the new final class in the file.

Comment: What was the name of the method that appeared to be triggering the help problem?

Comment: It didn't seem to be tied to any particular method. Moving things around kept changing which methods, and even which classes were causing the issue. When I swapped the positions of the last 2 classes in the module, the new last class in there was the problem, and the former, seemingly broken class and all of its methods were fine.

Comment: Would you mind trying to run `help` on a normal install of Python 2.6? It could be something with the way it was compiled with Maya.

Comment: Also, can you post the smallest bit of code that causes the error? Is it 64 bit or 32 bit Maya?

Comment: It's 64-bit Win 7. I guess code doesn't work in these small comments, so I'll add it to the end of my original post.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Python 2.6 installed separately here. I have 2.7, and I did try it in there in the Windows shell. There were issues with the file containing Maya-based code and imports, so I commented that stuff out, but it wouldn't seem to take. I also deleted the .pyc file and even exited python and reentered in the shell, but it still kept saying those lines I had commented out were in there and causing a conflict. It must have its own temp space for the pyc files. Unfortunately I had to stop as it's a busy work day.

Answer (score 0):

when you import maya modules say

```
import maya.cmds as cmds # or
import maya.mel as mel
```

*make sure you must put as cmds or as mel part at the end of each import*

then you use lets say

```
cmds.sphere()
```

maya also defines its own help function!!! help()

otherwise you will end up mixing/overriding some of the methods defined by maya over python's, this could also be the reason why you getting the strange result .

I do not think if you move your class anywhere up in the module will make any difference because when an object is instantiated it is irrelevant of its placement in the OO code...